# Ssis error invalid column reference in package

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ssis

I have an invalid column reference error in my sis package after editing my stored procedure with a case statement which added a column total sales from amount paid. Please can someone help with this? I cannot remap the columns in the package unless I resolve the error. Thanks

Comment: Can you share code or screenshots of what you see?

Comment: Could you please provide more details about what your package does, how data is flowing, where you are getting error and at which component.

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar problem in my SSIS package. After adding a few new columns to my source table the "OLE DB Source" element would not map these new columns correctly either not displaying them at all on the mapping list or showing the "invalid column" error.
It turned out that the connection I was using had the **RetainSameConnection** parameter set to **True** (the package uses temp tables that are not to be dropped) - changing this to **False** enabled me to add the new columns to the mapping.
It might also be a good idea to check the **DelayValidation** and **ValidateExternalMetadata** parameters on elements connected to the data flow. These should probably be set to True in this case.

Perhaps someone runs into the same problem.

Comment: RetainSameConnection was my problem. Our Test DB hasn't been updated yet but Dev has been. The Test DB connection was being retained and I couldn't figure out why. This fixed it. Good Catch!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that SSIS external metadata refresh is happened. If you change an underlying query that your SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) package is relying on, you get the same message.

You can fix it by using Restore Invalid Column References Editor.Use this dialog box to restore the mappings of invalid column references. Set the Available Columns item to "" for all the entries and click OK. You should then be able to continue and remap the columns between source and destination.

If you couldn't see Restore Invalid Column References Editor then follow below steps.

1. Right-clicking the box with the warning sign
2. Selecting "Show Advanced Editor"
3. Activating "Column Mappings"
4. Clicking "Refresh"

Otherwise delete destination connection and rebuilding it from scratch.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to ignore the error, and remapped the columns. It runs fine.